# use filter function within summarise function from dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Is there a way to use the filtering function inside the summarise for example:

```
#I have a dataset with 5 columns Price, Type, Amount USD, date 
# I only want the mean price of the rows that are not Type == "SELL"

data = summarise(Price = filter(!Type == "SELL") %>% mean(Price), Amount = sum(Amount), USD = sum(USD), date = min(date))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use :

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  summarise(Price = mean(Price[Type != 'SELL']), 
            Amount = sum(Amount), 
            USD = sum(USD), 
            date = min(date))
```

To use it in pipes :

```
data %>%
  summarise(Price = mean(data %>% filter(Type != 'SELL') %>% pull(Price)), 
            Amount = sum(Amount), 
            USD = sum(USD), 
            date = min(date))
```

Comment: thanks, so just to be sure it's not possible to use pipes inside the summarise function?

Comment: It is, but I find it very convoluted for this task. See updated answer.